# kohana ORM user model can't validate other users rows, for example Name, Last Name etc

Tags: validation, kohana, admin, addition

In what areas do change so check was? I do not want to check for a password field for compatibility repeating field.

My add function in Kohana Users Controller

```
public function action_add() {
        $title = 'Add User';
        $this->template->title = $title;
        $this->template->content = View::factory('action/users/add')
                ->bind('title', $title)
                ->bind('message', $message)
                ->bind('errors', $errors);

        if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method()) {
            try {

                // Create the user using form values
                $user = ORM::factory('user')->create_user($this->request->post(), array(
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    'email',
                    'last_name',
                    'first_name',
                    'middle_name'
                        ));

                // Grant user login role
                $user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));

                // Reset values so form is not sticky
                $_POST = array();

                Session::instance()->set('message', "You have added user '{$user->username}' to the database");
                Request::current()->redirect('/admin/' . $this->request->param('lang') . '/action/users' );
            } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {

                // Set failure message
                $message = 'There were errors, please see form below.';

                // Set errors using custom messages
                $errors = $e->errors('models');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use directly the ORM::create() method,

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#create_user

what ORM::create_user() does is validate the password, just what you want to skip

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#create_user

so you should use something like

```
  $user = ORM::factory('user')->values($this->request->post(), array(
                'username',
                'password',
                'email',
                'last_name',
                'first_name',
                'middle_name'
                    ))->create();
```

Avoiding to call the create_user, you will avoid the password length validation too, so normally you will add this rule at the model, but since the password get hash you should handle it at the controller, I see you are not using any validation or filter for the $POST data, I would recommend you tu use the Validator object

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Validation

with it you could restrict the password length